# Uri Path Extension Mapping in Web API

Tags: .net, routes, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get Uri Path Extension Mapping working in Web API. I have the routes set up correctly:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
                       name: "Api with extension",
                       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{ext}/{id}",
                       defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, ext = RouteParameter.Optional }
                   );

routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
```

And it works ok with the default route, e.g. ***/api/products.json/123*** but for other methods e.g. ***/api/products.json?categoryid=5*** I get an error message:

```
"No action was found on the controller 'Products' that matches the request."
```

All the routing works find without the extension e.g. ***/api/products/123*** and ***/api/products?categoryid=5***. Anyone any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: please coud you post actions which map these two routes?

Comment: They would map to: _GetProduct(int id)_ and _GetProductsByCategory(int categoryid)_

Answer (score 8):

If anyone else comes across this, then the answer (how to get Uri Extension mapping working) may  likely be the following (this worked for myself, after much frustration and searching)

Add the following to your web.config, into the System.WebServer section

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`/api/products.json?categoryid=5` will map to the following controller action:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public string Get(int categoryid)
    {
        return categoryid.ToString();
    }
}
```

So make sure this controller and action exists. In the comments section you seem to have indicated some `GetProduct(int id)` and `GetProductsByCategory(int categoryid)` actions but those will never be used. According to RESTful conventions, the `Get` action will be invoked when you use the `GET` verb. If you want to use some non-RESTful action names make sure that you include the `{action}` in the route definition.

Comment: My routes are working fine, it's only when I try to use the UriPathExtensionMapping that they fail. It's my understanding that it's the URI that determines which action get's called, so the URI _/api/products?categoryid=5_ matches the signature of the action _GetProductsById(int categoryid)_ so the call gets routed there. All the code is based it part on this tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api and works fine without the Extension - it's only that I'm having problems getting working.